# URL issue in Docker Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, docker

I wanted to create a local dev environment for a wordpress site using docker.
So I have the following docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${WP_DB_NAME}
    - MYSQL_USER=${WP_DB_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${WP_DB_USER_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
    #- ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./mysql_dump/backup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sql
    - ./mysql_dump/migrate.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrate.sql
    networks:
    - local

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
    - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
    - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${WP_DB_USER}
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${WP_DB_USER_PASSWORD}
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${WP_DB_NAME}
    volumes: 
    - ./htdocs:/var/www/html
    networks:
      local:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.4

networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.23.0.0/24
```

I use volume to start mariadb with existing database dump.

Website is loading fine, but some URLs are wrong :

- When I try to connect, I am redirected to :
  `http://172.23.0.4/172.23.0.4/wp-admin/` for example
- Some js scripts are also not loaded due to wrong URLs like
  `http://172.23.0.4172.23.0.4/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js?ver=4920-20181217`

I checked the general settings in the admin panel, and the values `siteurl` and `home` in the database and they are correct : `172.23.0.4`.
The website in production (no docker but classic LAMP install) is working fine by the way…

Do you have any hints ? (I'm not that familiar with web development, especially with wordpress)

Comment: Did you check `siteurl` **and** `home` option in database ?

Comment: Yes, they are both set to "172.23.0.4"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like specifying `172.23.0.4` in wordpress settings for `home` and `siteurl` is somehow (don't know why though) causing the issue.
Instead, setting the value to `http://172.23.0.4` fixed the problem.

If someone has some explanation, please tell me.

Comment: I'm setting `home` and `siteurl` to this value. In the wordpress admin panel, but we can find these values in MySQL table